# Is there any difference between IPA ‘ and ʰ?

Tags: ipa

Is there any difference between IPA ‘ and ʰ?

I've seen /kʰ/ also written as /k’/.

Is there any fundamental difference between letter‘ and letterʰ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The letter <’> is used in IPA to indicate an ejective consonant, which is quite distinct from <ʰ> which represents aspiration. The use of <’> to mark aspiration is not IPA usage  (please note that IPA is just one of many traditions for phonetic transcription). Presumably you are looking at an older source, or a more language-specific source that isn't aimed at phoneticians.

*[Vowels and Consonants](http://www.phonetics.ucla.edu/vowels/chapter12/quechua.html)* provides sound files for Quechua, which John Lawler mentioned. Zulu and Xhosa also have aspirates vs. ejectives, but the ejectives are much weaker. The [UCLA archive of Zulu](http://archive.phonetics.ucla.edu/Language/ZUL/zul.html) has some examples, in the [second wordlist](http://archive.phonetics.ucla.edu/Language/ZUL/zul_word-list_1964_01.html), starting around 2:30 of this [sound file](http://archive.phonetics.ucla.edu/Language/ZUL/zul_word-list_1964_01.wav).

Comment: Also, [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/yB6H3bDemAU) provides with an example of how ejective consonants differ from aspirated ones.

Comment: Quechua has phonemically distinct series of plain, ejective, and aspirated stops. Using IPA symbols, that would be /q/, /q̓/, and /qʰ/.